The X-Factor: 18 And Over

The three overlapping ellipses form seven regions.  Place exactly one tile per region so that the tiles in each ellipse obey its rule.
Is the solution unique?

rot18(Q bpqvs bpm xzwlckb bew vcujmza qv jwbp xzwlckb kqzktma kiv jm x, ivl bpm lqnnmzmvkm wn bpm xzwlckba wn bpm xiqza wn vcujmza qv rcab wvm wn bpm xzwlckb kqzktma kiv jm y. Em pidm xy=18.)


  The two product ellipses give two products that are both odd or even, so since $bedfcg$ is even, $x$ is too. $bedfcg$ is divisible by at least $2^4$, and so is $bed^2f^2cg$, meaning either $bedf$ or $cgdf$ is divisible by $8$, with the other being a $4k+2$ number. $bedfcg$ is also divisible by at least $3^3$ and so is $bed^2f^2cg$, meaning either $bedf$ or $cgdf$ is divisible by $9$, but then if one is divisible by $9$, so is the other, making $bed^2f^2cg$ divisible by $81$. $df(cg-be)=18$.  $df = 2, 3, 6, 9, 18$  $cg-be = 9, 6, 3, 2, 1$  $d$ and $f$ can't be both even. They can't be $4$ or $12$ either.  $a+b+c+d = 18$  Since 18 is an even number, there must be $2$ or $0$ odd numbers among the four, the latter of which is impossible because $2+4+6+12>18$. So, the sum could be $1+2+3+12, 1+2+6+9$ or $2+3+4+9$.  That means only one of $e, f$ and $g$ is odd, and none of them can be $2$.  1- If $f$ is odd:  $e$ and $g$ are even but not $2$, so they can be $4, 6$ or $12$. $cg-be$ is also even, making $d$ also odd because $18$ isn't divisible by $4$. $df= 3$ or $9$. One of them must be $1$.  $cg-be=6$ or $2$  1a- If $a,b,c,d$ are $1,2,3$ and $12$ in no particular order:  Then $e,f$ and $g$ are $4,6$ and $9$ in no particular order. $f$ can only be $9$ and $d=1$, meaning $cg-be=2$. $e$ and $g$ are $4$ and $6$ in no particular order. In this subtraction, the product containing $4$ is divisible by $4$, so the other one, which contains the $6$, must also contain an odd number for the difference to be $2$. This odd number can only be $3$. $3 \times 4 = 12$, but neither $10$ nor $14$ can be a product of two of the numbers.  1b- If $a,b,c,d$ are $1,2,6$ and $9$ in no particular order:  Then $e,f$ and $g$ are $3,4$ and $12$ in no particular order. $f$ can only be $3$ and $d=1$, meaning $cg-be=6$. $e$ and $g$ are $4$ and $12$ in no particular order, but that means $cg-be$ should be divisible by $4$, which is a contradiction.  1c- If $a,b,c,d$ are $2,3,4$ and $9$ in no particular order:  Then $e,f$ and $g$ are $1,6$ and $12$ in no particular order. $f$ can only be $1$ and $d=3$ or $9$, meaning $cg-be=6$ or $2$. $e$ and $g$ are $6$ and $12$ in no particular order, so the difference should be divisible by $6$, $cg-be=6$ and $d=3$. In this subtraction, the product containing $12$ is divisible by $12$, so the other one, which contains the $6$, must also contain an odd number for the difference to be $6$. This odd number can only be $9$. $9 \times 6 = 54$ and $4 \times 12=48$. This makes a solution possible:  $a=2$  $b=4$  $c=9$  $d=3$  $e=12$  $f=1$  $g=6$   2- If $f$ is even:  $f=6$. Either $e$ or $g$ is also even but not $2$, so it can be $4$ or $12$. $d=1$ or $3$ and $cg-be=3$ or $1$.  2a- If $a,b,c,d$ are $1,2,3$ and $12$ in no particular order:  Then $e$ and $g$ are $4$ and $9$ in no particular order. In this subtraction, the product containing $4$ can contain at most $12$ as the other term, so the product is at most $48$, meaning the other product, which contains the $9$, can have at most $3$ as the other term ($5$ doesn't exist and $4$ is already used). The latter also has to be odd. Only $9 \times 1=9$ can allow the subtraction and make a solution possible:  $a=12$  $b=2$  $c=1$  $d=3$  $e=4$  $f=6$ $g=9$  2b- If $a,b,c,d$ are $2,3,4$ and $9$ in no particular order:  Then $e$ and $g$ are $1$ and $12$ in no particular order. $d=3$, meaning $cg-be=1$. In this subtraction, the product containing $12$ is divisible by $12$, so the other one, which contains the $1$, must also contain another odd number for the difference to be $1$, but this product can be $9$ at most and makes the subtraction false.


Presumably abcdefg are assigned to the individual regions, but it's far from obvious which letter goes with which region. A diagram would help..

I was going to post one, but forgot it. Fixed. Also sorted the variables from $a$ to $g$ in proper order for the solution cases.

Not sure if this qualifies, but, for the fun of it, I have solved it with a piece of Prolog/CLP(FD), i.e. Constraint Logic Programming over Finite Domains in Prolog.
Let A, B, C, D, E, F, G be the regions, where A is the top-left region, then B to F are the next regions in clockwise order, finally G is the central region.
We find

 exactly 2 solutions:
 A = 2, B = 4, C = 12, D = 1, E = 6, F = 9, G = 3 
 and
 A = 12, B = 2, C = 4, D = 6, E = 9, F = 1, G = 3 

Here is the code, for GNU Prolog though it should be easily adaptable to other systems:

%% GNU Prolog 1.5.0

xfactor(A, B, C, D, E, F, G) :-
  Vs = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G],
  fd_domain(Vs, [1,2,3,4,6,9,12]),  % DOM
  fd_all_different(Vs),             % DIFF
  A + B + F + G #= 18,      % SUM = 18
  B * C * D * G #= X,       % PROD = X
  D * E * F * G #= X + 18,  % PROD = X + 18
  fd_labelingff(Vs).  % solve


